# How is the Bitnami djangostack created and is it a virtualenv?

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv, bitnami

I have used the Bitnami Djangostack before but I am not sure if this creates some type of virtualenv or what is the underlying mechanism on how it works or how it is put together.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami stacks are self-contained. In the `/opt/bitnami/` folder you can find the most important assets to have a running Django application (from https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/django/)

- Python language
- Django framework
- Apache Web server
- MySQL database server (optional)
- PostgreSQL database server (optional)
- GeoDjango and PostGIS
- Mod_wsgi